# Struts spring Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

There shows an Error in Configuring application listener of class

and this is my Error actually

> **
>
> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
>
> **
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:927)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:298)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1626)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) strong text
>
> ```
> **
> ```
>
> **SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
>
> ****  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:927)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:298)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1626)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Here is my

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <description>iSAS</description>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <!-- <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class> -->
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and 
my

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">       
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>

        <action name="userRegistration_*" method="{1}" class="userRegistration">
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">isas.user.registration</result>
            <result name="ERROR" type="tiles">isas.errorPage</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">isas.user.registration</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

Here I have Used the spring-2.5.6 jar before, now instead of it I am using spring-1.0.2.jar
I need know what are the exact jar files needed for this error.

Comment: What servlet container and what version of the container are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use similar versions of jar. use struts-spring plugin jar and struts-tiles plugin as well. Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

It is missing a jar file. `ServletContextListener` is in `servlet-api.jar` include that jar file in your project. (`ServletRequestListener` is in the same jar file)

Comment: Sir I have included servlet-api-6.0.14.jar but then it is not working